# Avoid page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, webforms

I have to avoid page refresh. Every time I click the submit button, page is refreshed. How do I avoid that?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstname = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

    if (firstname == "All")
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    }

    dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.DataTable1;
    da.Fill(dt);
    rdc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
    rdc.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdc;
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting everything that needs to be updated in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.
You can find that control in the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

You will also have to add a `<asp:ScriptManager>` on top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want a full page refresh either use UpdatePanel for partial rendering or proper ajax approach.

the way you are doing now with a server side button click is the slowest and generates a full page postback and refresh unless you use an UpdatePanel at minimum.

check here for a discussion on how to use the Crystal Report viewer with Ajax: [using AJAX with crystal report viewer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1338345.aspx/1)